# Kendo drop down does not work in my fiddle but works in Kendo Sample

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to follow this example of Kendo drop down.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist

This is the way I am trying to create kendo drop down.

```
         var categories = $("#categories").kendoDropDownList({
                    optionLabel: "Select category...",
                    dataTextField: "CategoryName",
                    dataValueField: "CategoryID",
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "odata",
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        transport: {
                            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Categories"
                        }
                    }
                }).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

drop downs are not coming for me
Here is my version

http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmangalore/2d5spqf4/

Same code in KENDO Sample works
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist

Comment: What do you mean "drop downs are not coming" ? I see the drop down at fiddle

Comment: sorry, i pasted wrong fiddle. Now I added my fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmangalore/2d5spqf4/

Answer (score 0):

They are not coming because you are not including KendoUI libraries (JavaScripts and CSS).

The only thing that you need to do is click on "External Resources" in the left column and add:

```
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.common.min.css
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.default.min.css
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/jquery.min.js
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/kendo.all.min.js
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2d5spqf4/1/